# Where can I buy Mana III potions?

Tags: white-knight-chronicles-2

I'm at a point in the game where I need a lot of heavy mana spells to get through this one part, but the best I can find is Mana Potion II in stores. Is it possible to purchase these from a store or do I have to bind them?

Comment: As mentioned in this question: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5507/how-to-handle-untagged-questions, we are now retagging [tag:untagged] questions in the hope that the pruner gets shut off. I have no idea what this game is, so can you retag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy them from the [Guild Shop](http://whiteknightchronicles.neoseeker.com/wiki/Guild%20Shop).

Certain [Bounty quests](http://whiteknightchronicles.neoseeker.com/wiki/Bounties#Part_II_White_Knight_Chronicles_2) also reward Mana Potions.